# Wikidata SPARQL query with label not working

Tags: sparql, wikidata

I can't understand why with this query I can't get movement and genre labels:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel ?value ?inception ?creatorLabel ?image
                 (group_concat(?genreLabel; separator=", ") AS ?genres)
                 (group_concat(?movementLabel; separator=", ") AS ?movements)
WHERE {
  ?item wdt:P4610 ?value;
        wdt:P18 ?image.  #with an image
  OPTIONAL { ?item wdt:P571 ?inception; #optionally with creationdate
            wdt:P170 ?creator; #Optionally with creator
            wdt:P136 ?genre;
            wdt:P135 ?movement.
           }

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "it,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]"}
} GROUP BY ?item ?itemLabel ?image ?value ?inception ?creatorLabel
ORDER BY ?item
```

I've tried in many ways, but it seems it's always wrong.

Comment: 1. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SPARQL/SERVICE_-_Label#Manual_Label_SERVICE 2. Perhaps you need separate `OPTIONAL`s.

Comment: StanislavKralin is right, it has to be `SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "it,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]" .
                         ?genre rdfs:label ?genreLabel . ?movement rdfs:label ?movementLabel}`

Comment: Yes, perfect! Many thanks