# wikidata SPARQL to get property:Label when using SAMPLE()

Tags: sparql, wikidata, sparqlwrapper

I'm having trouble getting the Label to pull through when using a DISTINCT and SAMPLE query.

My [query](https://w.wiki/5dW) pulls companies and a sample of some basic attributes / properties. I would like to get the raw text label for ?state but no matter which way I try it does not seem to work.

I have tried adding "

> ?state rdfs:label ?stateLabel"

in SERVICE as outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53555442/wikidata-sparql-query-with-label-not-working) but this seems to mess up the wikibase:label behavior .

Kind thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: what's wrong with doing what was suggested in the answer you referred to? either `SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel . ?state rdfs:label ?stateLabel . }` or just the way with `OPTIONAL`? works for me as expected

Comment: and what is the reason for having braces around each triple pattern inside your last `OPTIONAL` clause?

Comment: When I try the solution in the answer and your first suggestion it seems to not pass through itemLabel,web and isin etc. But yes it does work for stateLabel. https://w.wiki/5da

Please could you provide the of the working query if you have one.

Comment: I think I cannot follow you. I did post a working variant. Do exactly what I posted in my previous comment: `SERVICE wikibase:label {bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". ?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel . ?state rdfs:label ?stateLabel . }` - and yes, if you use this you have to bind all labels explicitly in the SERVICE clause as I also did for the `?itemLabel` var. At least, I can see `?itemLabel` values. What might happen is that you got some results that don't have a label for `rdfs:label` though I doubt those exist in Wikidata

Comment: Thank you, but this causes the query to timeout: https://w.wiki/5dd.

Comment: I know, but this is just because your query is slow resp. complex in general. Even without my suggestion it takes "ages" to return a result.

Comment: My initial query works and returns 100K results in some 30 seconds. It seems strange / unbelievable that simply extracting the English label of an returned object would add that much overhead. I think there is a simple trick missing.

Comment: it has something to do with how labels are handled for SAMPLE / OPTIONAL queries.

Comment: There is no "trick" or something. In the end, any OPTIONAL is a left-outer join. Alternative suggestion, remove the label SERVICE and do `?item rdfs:label ?itemLabel. filter(lang(?itemLabel) = "en")` - and indeed analogous for the stateLabel inside the OPTIONAL